# C++ Lambda saved in vector executed multiple times

Tags: c++

I am doing some C++ library for embedded and I need to create a callback functionality. I want to be able to register member functions and lambdas as well. I tried this (simplified) without much luck:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

typedef const std::function<void (int)> connection_handler_t;
std::vector<connection_handler_t*> connectionHandlerList;

void addConnectionHandler(connection_handler_t& h) {
  connectionHandlerList.push_back(&h);
}

void runConnectionHandlers() {
  std::cout << "Running registered connection handlers" << std::endl;

  for (auto& handler : connectionHandlerList) {
    (*handler)(16);
  }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "testing vector" << std::endl;

    addConnectionHandler([=](int i) {
        std::cout << "a: " << i << std::endl;
    });

    addConnectionHandler([=](int i) {
        std::cout << "b: " << i << std::endl;
    });

    runConnectionHandlers();
}
```

My output is:

```
testing vector
Running registered connection handlers
b: 16
b: 16
```

My expected result would be:

```
testing vector
Running registered connection handlers
a: 16
b: 16
```

Why is it running always the same last lambda X times?
I am working on client library for Java server, so I am new to the C++

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using **pointers to** `std::function`?  You should be using `std::function` as-is instead. Your mistake is due to the compiler creating 2 temporary `std:::function` objects that you are adding to your `vector` by pointer, and those objects happen to use the same memory address on the call stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the shown code exhibits undefined behavior. With my compiler, for example, I get your expected results, but only because of random chance.

```
addConnectionHandler([=](int i) {
    std::cout << "a: " << i << std::endl;
});
```

This creates a temporary object, and passes it to `addConnectionHandler()`. After this function returns, this temporary object gets destroyed.

Inside `addConnectionHandler()`:

```
connectionHandlerList.push_back(&h);
```

This is going to save a pointer to the passed-in object in a vector.

Unfortunately, as I explained, the passed-in object is a temporary object, and will be destroyed as soon as this function returns. The saved pointer points to a destroyed object.

The code that follows attempts to use the saved pointers to dereference and invoke the type-erased lambdas. However, since those pointers are dangling, and point to a destroyed object, this results in undefined behavior. You might see different behavior, or even a crash, with each invocation of your program.

There is no need to use pointers here. Simply have a vector of `std::function` objects, and push your input `std::function` as-is directly into the vector. No pointers are needed in this use case.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @SamVarshavchik's comment, but considering how this isn't your actual code, I'll try and speculate and give some advice.

It's quite possible that your use of *pointers* to *temporary objects* results in the the first "callback" pointer pointing at the exact same location where the second "callback" has been instantiated - as the first one is no longer used.

So, if you:

1. Use a vector of `connection_handler`'s, not pointers to them
2. `emplace_back` or insert these handlers rather than inserting pointers to them

You should be at least safe from what you've described. And actually, you should just do that regardless of the behavior you've seen.

PS:

- Don't use the global variable, it's highly unlikely you really need it. And if you do use it - watch out for concurrent access to it.
- Don't call a vector of Thing a "ThingList" -  it's not a list.

Comment: Hello, your answer is good as well. I edited the code a little bit. I am using class variable for it in my real code. It was just a quick show off of the problem. Thank you for vector vs list comment.